# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout while library is updated and AppTheme is also updated

Tags: android, material-design-in-xaml

I am getting this error after changing the material design library
These are the things which I am using in my project

**library**
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

**XML file**

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:theme="@style/App_EditTextStyle_Pass_Info"
          >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_passenger_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. "
            android:hint="Enter Name"
            />
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Style XML file**

```
     <style name="App_EditTextStyle_Pass_Info" 
        parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_large</item>
        <item name="android:freezesText">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal"></item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:height">55dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff444444</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dark_grey</item>
     </style>
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
     </style>
```

Comment: Using `AndroidX` ??

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Yes I am migrating my project to AndroidX api level 29

Comment: People should be warned that you never mark an answer as accepted.